# org.jbpm vs org.kie.kogito jBPM

Tags: jbpm, bpmn, kogito

I have been trying to figure out what the difference is between the org.jbpm and org.kie.kogito variant of jBPM.

I have seen that the maven artefacts differ quite a bit, even through the org.jbpm does in turn refer to the org.kie parent POM.

Can anyone share some light on this? If I wanted to implement a process flow (bpmn2) without all the additional features of Kogito, what would the the best course to go? Using the org.jbpm or the org.kie.kogito package?

Answer (score 0):

We sort of answered this question [here](https://kie.zulipchat.com/#narrow/stream/232678-jbpm/topic/Inquiry.20Regarding.20Continuity.20of.20Support.20and.20Maintenance.20JBPM/near/373036465)

To briefly answer your question, you should use Kogito.